# Are username and password sent in plain text when using windows authentication type in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, security

If I have the following binding:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Binding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Will the username and password be send on plain text over the wire?

### Edit

I know that by default wcf encrypts the connection. The reason why I asked the question is because of:

[image]

I got that from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354513.aspx

**So my question is** I know that the connection is encrypted by default. But do I need a ssl certificate in order to prevent users from seeing the username and password. I know that once I am authenticated messages will be encrypted. But is the password and username encrypted too?

Comment: You have transport security turned on. So while a username and password might be plaintext in the message, but it will be encrypted by the transport protocol.

Comment: thanks for the comment!. So that means that yes the username and password are sent encrypted regardless if I do not specify any sort of serviceCertificate like the one from the link I showed right?

Comment: The channel is encrypted without need of ssl (in the case of transport, which should be used in cases of intranet, not extranet or internet).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other answers here are misleading and incorrect, although they may reassure you by mentioning transport security. The correct answer is that **Windows Authentication does not send passwords in plain text.**

Windows authentication works when the client guarantees to the server that the user is who they say they are. No password is transmitted over the wire.

If you were to use Basic Authentication then the password would be transmitted over the wire; if using any `https` transport then the connection is encrypted but within that connection the content of the message is not encrypted.

See [How secure is WCF wsHttpBinding's Windows authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906685/how-secure-is-wcf-wshttpbindings-windows-authentication) a similar question.

See [MSDN Message and Transport Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648863.aspx) for more about WCF transport security.

Comment: He was asking about his particular piece of code, no need to be Captain Obvious...

Answer (score 2):

Data sent over the wire, contained in the message is in plain text; however, given that Transport security mode is being used, the client-server communication is being secured via ssl over http (and TLS in the case of TCP).

More can be read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648589.aspx) about how Transport secures communication.

But because neither of the communicating parties are required to understand xml-level security concepts, the actual xml of a message is sent in plain text.

**EDIT**: Kirk Broadhurst is correct - in the case of Windows Authentication, username and password are not attached to/present on the message, but any data present is not encrypted.

Comment: thanks for the help. If I use net.tcp instead of wsHttp using windows authentication that will still be secure rigth? I guess I have to read more about it. Thanks

Comment: so - if you specify Transport, the channel is equally as secure. If you want message level security where the password is hashed or encrypted on the actual message, you'll want to actually implement an x509 cert. [Here's some more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280819/wcf-how-do-i-encrypt-messages).

Answer (score 0):

WsHttpBinding encrypts messages by default so it will not be plain text.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647344.aspx).